# How to align text with a matrix?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, tikz-matrix

quite new to Latex,
I have wrote down the following Tex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,arrows.meta,arrows}

\tikzset{
    mymat/.style={
        matrix of math nodes,
        text height=2.5ex,
        text depth=0.75ex,
        text width=3.25ex,
        align=center,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth
    },
    mymats/.style={
        mymat,
        nodes={draw,fill=#1}
    }  
}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
        \node(array_a) {Array A};
        
        \matrix[mymat,right=of array_a,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
        at (0,0) 
        (mat1)
        {
            0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
            2 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
        };
        
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

which resulted with:

[image]

We can see the **array name is not aligned with the array illustration in the y axis**.

Can someone please suggest how can I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Do you really need a hammersledge like tikz to do that? It's quite easy with `blkarray`.

Comment: I'd say it is easier to do it the other way, make the `\matrix` first and then add `Array A` relative to the node `mat1-2-1`

Comment: @daleif thank you, 
I have tried now: \node(array_a) [left=of mat1] {Array A}; 
But still it's unaligned :/

Comment: `mat1` does not refer to an element as such, it is the overall name of the matrix. See Ignasis answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As daleif proposed, it's easier to put the label after the matrix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,arrows.meta,arrows}

\tikzset{
    mymat/.style={
        matrix of math nodes,
        text height=2.5ex,
        text depth=0.75ex,
        text width=3.25ex,
        align=center,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth
    },
    mymats/.style={
        mymat,
        nodes={draw,fill=#1}
    }  
}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
      
        \matrix[mymat, row 2/.style={nodes=draw, anchor=center}]
        at (0,0) 
        (mat1)
        {
              0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
              2 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
        };
        
        \node[left = 12mm of mat1-2-1.base, anchor=base] (array_a) {Array A};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative solution could be to use `matrix anchor` option to select an inner node as reference:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,arrows.meta,arrows}

\tikzset{
    mymat/.style={
        matrix of math nodes,
        text height=2.5ex,
        text depth=0.75ex,
        text width=3.25ex,
        align=center,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth
    },
    mymats/.style={
        mymat,
        nodes={draw,fill=#1}
    }  
}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]

        \node (array_a) {Array A};
      
        \matrix[mymat, row 2/.style={nodes=draw},
            right=of array_a, matrix anchor=mat1-2-1.west]
        at (0,0) 
        (mat1)
        {
              0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
              2 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
        };
        
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

How about this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
\draw (0,0) grid (5,1);
\foreach \i/\j in {0/2,1/1,2/3,3/2,4/1}
\path (\i+.5,1.5) node{\i} (\i+.5,.5) node{\j};
\path (-.5,.5) node[left]{Array A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Update:** To make horizontal alignment

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
\draw (0,0) grid (5,1);
\foreach \i/\j in {0/2,1/1,2/3,3/2,4/1}
\path (\i+.5,1.5) node {\i} (\i+.5,.5) node (\i) {\j};

\path (0.base) node[left=1.5cm,anchor=base]{Array A};

% for checking baseline alignment only
\draw[red] (0.base)--++(0:5) (0.base)--++(180:3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Black Mild, I appreciate the help!

Comment: @JammingThebBits: Just a bit curiosity: Why did you accept the longer answer? ^^

Comment: just because, It was similar to the code which I have posted. Thank you again, your code is elegant!

Comment: Very strange excuse...

Comment: @JammingThebBits I point out the reason my old answer should not be accepted: text `Array A` and right texts did not have the same baseline. I have just add an update for that.

Answer (score 4):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

Array A\quad
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}[hvlines,first-row,baseline=0]
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
2 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\vspace{2cm}
Array A\quad
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}[hvlines,first-row,baseline=1]
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
2 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{NiceTabular}
        
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]